# Does speed affect space?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, speed, relative-motion

Since gravity can affect time, speed can affect time, what would a high amount of kinetic energy look like on a model for the fabric of space? Such as with the models of bent space beneath planets, if a planet was moving ludicrously fast, would it look like it had a different effect than that of a relatively slow moving planet? I ask as a curious fool who has heard that space and time are very much related.

Comment: *models of bent space beneath planets* Space isn’t bent “beneath” planets. You’ve seen too many pictures trying to explain gravity as a trampoline with a bowling ball on it. These are just pop-sci metaphors.

Comment: The simplest effect of speed on space is Lorentz contraction, and it has nothing to do with gravity.

Comment: "*gravity can affect time*" - You have this in reverse. Gravitational attraction is not a cause, but a result of time dilation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of knowledge about this, but this is what I understand --

Gravity affects spacetime by stretching and distorting the amount of space and the length of time, and speed affects your perspective of time as you slowly get closer to the speed of light, or in this sense, the speed of causality, the "information" around you seems to be moving slower. If you were going the speed of light, the light bouncing off of a clock will never be able to reach your eyes and as a result, that clock will look like it's not ticking.

I think the recent LIGO discovery might answer your question; as two black holes were collapsing in on each other, their immense mass and speed created gravitational waves, or ripples in spacetime, right before they combined. That was eventually detected 1.6 billion lightyears away here on earth.

In the case of a planet, I don't think it would be able to go fast enough without actually distorting the spacetime surrounding it, and in doing so would change how the planet would react with the undisturbed spacetime around that, and I'm not entirely sure how that would look.

Comment: Gotta clarify, LIGO only confirmed what Einstein theorized. Gravitational waves were already thought to exist, LIGO only just confirmed their existence.

Comment: "*I don't have a lot of knowledge about this*" - Fortunately there are many ways to learn to make sure you do have enough knowledge on the subject to answer questions of others. This site is not a forum to share personal opinions, but a question and answer site to share the knowledge of physics.

Comment: "*LIGO only confirmed what Einstein theorized*" - Gravitational waves were first proposed by Henri Poincare in 1905, as emanating from a body at the speed of light and required by the Lorentz transformations. Einstein's 1918 paper on gravitational waves contained an error. In 1936 he and Rosen claimed that gravitational waves did not exist. Their paper was initially rejected due to an error that was later corrected by Howard Robertson. The theory of gravitational waves was established in late 1950s by Hermann Bondi, Felix Pirani, Ivor Robinson, and Andrzej Trautman after the death of Einstein.